# Elasticsearch as primary data source for chat application

Tags: database, elasticsearch, datasource

As per many questions from stackoverflow, to choose elasticsearch as a primary datasource is solely depends on the usecase. So if I want to implement chat application similar to Microsoft teams or any, Will it be a good idea to use it as a primary source of truth?

I want to implement app-wide search in the application.

reads are more than writes. around 1000 reads per sec while writes could just be just 20 per sec plus files upto size 10MB

another point worth mentioning would be that the data type is json data and the search is done on all textual data from a given set of fields

Comment: This also depends on what kind of chat application you are trying to build. Elasticsearch is definitely faster than MySQL and other similar databases.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use apache cassandra. it is developed by facebook engineer as chat server and it was donated as open source project to apache at 2008.

elasticsearch is a search engine and it is suitable if you want all kind of search on user's chat content.

cassandra is very faster in read/write and you can support more user than elasticsearch.